# How I can disable font smoothing on imagick?

Tags: php, fonts, imagick, smoothing

I use php+imagick and can not turn off font smoothing. When I used the GD, could simply set a negative font color and smoothing switching off.

Comment: Hmmmm. This could be difficult. Can you show what kind of effect you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Are you using the extension, or are you shelling out to the individual programs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to render text without font smoothing:

```
$background = new Imagick('path/to/image.png');
$drawText = new ImagickDraw();
$drawText->setfont('images/hoogles.ttf');
$drawText->settextantialias(false);
$drawText->annotation(0, 0, 'Hello world!');
$background->drawimage($drawText);
$background->writeimage('path/to/result.png');
```